# Understanding a simple dockerfile of postgresql

Tags: docker

I was just reading a docker file **[HERE](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/~/dockerfile/)**.

and basically the Dockerfile looks like follows:

```
FROM postgres:9.1
MAINTAINER Mike Dillon <mike@appropriate.io>

ENV POSTGIS_MAJOR 2.1
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.1.7+dfsg-3~94.git954a8d0.pgdg80+1

RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
           postgresql-$PG_MAJOR-postgis-$POSTGIS_MAJOR=$POSTGIS_VERSION \
           postgis=$POSTGIS_VERSION \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY ./initdb-postgis.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh
```

I want to make sure i have interpreted the below two commands correctly:

```
RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY ./initdb-postgis.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh
```

The RUN command is running a `mkdir` command , which means the current directory will have a subdirectory called:

```
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

andin the next command I.E. the COPY command the contents of the directory `./initdb-postgis.sh` are being copied into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh` , am i right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RUN cmd` is used to execute `cmd` command and will create and commit a new layer for the image your are building. So those commands are run in the context of the image that is being building. `mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` will create a new folder `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in the root of the image. `COPY ./initdb-postgis.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh` will copy the file `initdb-postgis.sh` (that has to be located at the same level you have run the `docker build command` to the file `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh` inside the container.